# DIV Href and dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog

Anyone can let me know how can i create div button that when user click on it will open dialog and in the same time will open new site in new tab.

**open dialog and open new site in new tab**

Please test the code before you put the answer.
By the way i'm using css bootstrap and jquery only.

Thanks,
Elias

Comment: What kind of dialog? An `alert` or an HTML modal of some kind?

Comment: You will need to add a lot more information if you want a quality answer. Also, please show us what you have tried by providing some code.

Comment: Dialog?An alert or a chat application? To open a new tab on click, add eventListener to an a element with target='_blank' value.Do not do it with a div button.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function openSite() {
    alert("Hello world");
    window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

```html
<div onclick="openSite();">Click me</div>
```

Replace the arguments to `alert` and `window.open` with your dialog text and the URL of the site to open, respectively.